# Printer CSS in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, printing, asset-pipeline

I'm working on a rails projects where I need to print an entire page and then it's divs individually. Even though my page is styled, none of the styling is showing up in the print.

My print.js looks like this:

```
function printDiv(divId) {
    window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML=document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
}

function printPage() {
    window.print()
}
```

Here is the head section of application.html.slim:

```
doctype html
html lang="en"
  head
    meta charset="utf-8"
    meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1"
    meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "ShellLoading"
    = csrf_meta_tags

    /! Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements
    /[if lt IE 9]
    = javascript_include_tag "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js"
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
```

Comment: The media query for your css is probably set to `screen`. Can you post the head part of your application layout?

Comment: @YuryLebedev I edited it into the question above. My colleagues are using slim and I'm not very familiar with that.

Comment: Strange, the media for the css file is set to `all`, so it should be applied for print too.

Comment: @YuryLebedev I'm wondering if I need a seperate print.css file and then need to include it in the asset pipeline. Or if I should include print media queries in my stylesheets?